# Select options from dependent dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, select, dropdown

I am trying to create a page as to select POP/IMAP  and their dependent options.

It works but in a messy way ie data stored is not exactly what it should be ie, the data selected is written to file but with blanks and information not desired.
I have just learnt some coding and would appreciate a little help please
I am enclosing file below

```
 22 
 23 <?php 
 24 
 25 $email=$_POST['email'];
 26 $server=$_POST['server'];
 27 $mail = fopen("data.txt", "a");
 28 fwrite($mail, $email );
 29 fwrite($mail, "\r\n" );
 30 fwrite($mail, $server);
 31 fwrite($mail, "\r\n" );
 32 
 33 ?>
 34 <div>
 35 <form method='GET'>
 36 <label for='type'><b>Receive  Type:</b></label>
 37 <select name ='type' id='type' onchange="mytype()">
 38 <option value='' selected>Select</option>
 39 <option value='POP' >POP </option>
 40 <option value='IMAP'>IMAP</option>
 41 </select>
 42 
 43 <script> 
 44 function mytype()
 45 {
 46 
 47         var x = document.getElementById("type").value;
 48         window.location.href = "mail_recv.php?Type="+x ;
 49 }
 50 </script>
 51 <?php
 52 $type=$_GET['Type'];
 53 fwrite($mail, $type);
 54 
 55 ?>
 56 </div>
 57 <div>
 58 <form method='GET'>
 59 <label for='port'><b>Receive Port:</b></label>
 60 <select name ='port' id='port' onchange='myport()'>
 61 
 62 <?php 
 63 
 64 if($type==='POP') { 
 65 echo "<option value='' selected>Select</option>";
 66 echo "<option value=Default:110>Default:110</option>";
 67 echo "<option value=TLS:995>TLS:995</option>";
 68 echo "</select>";
 69 }elseif($type==='IMAP') {
 70 echo "<option value='' selected>Select</option>";
 71 echo "<option value=Default:143>Default:143</option>";
 72 echo "<option value=TLS:993>TLS:993</option>";
 73 echo "</select>";
 74 echo "</div>";
 75 }else {
 76 echo "<option value='' selected>Select</option>";
 77 }
 78 ?>
  <script> 
  function myport()
  {
          var y = document.getElementById("port").value;
          window.location.href = "mail_recv.php?Port="+y ;
  }
  </script>
  
  <?php
```

Comment: Your option values should be enclosed in quotes

Comment: @Nick, thanks for your reply, However adding the quotes made no difference what so ever,   The following is what gets  written to the file the issue is that the line TLS 993 is written twice! Cant understand why and how to prevent it!                              "deepak@fdms.co.in
mail.yahoo.com
IMAP
TLS:993
TLS:993
123